# Form error - at submit click opens the window for downloading mail.php

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I create a form contact on a web, but when I click on "Enviar" (the submit button) the form email arrives but it opens a window to download the mail.php instead of showing the true form result. where is the error?
You can see it live in here: http://omgphotobooth.com.ar/jonetsugroup/contacto.php

this is the web code of the form:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="formValidar/formValidar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="formulario">
           <!--form-->
           <form id="web" method="POST" action="mail.php">
            <div class="campos">     
                <div class="caja">
                    <div class="flecha"></div>
                    <label class="tituloform" for="nombre">Nombre Completo
                    <span class="asterisk">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input name="nombre" class="ss-q-short" id="formNombre" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="caja">
                    <div class="flecha"></div>
                    <label class="tituloform" for="telefono">Teléfono
                    <span class="asterisk"></span>
                    </label>
                    <input name="telefono" class="ss-q-short" id="formTelefono" type="number">
                </div>
                <div class="caja">
                    <div class="flecha"></div>
                    <label class="tituloform" for="email">Mail
                    <span class="asterisk">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input name="email" class="ss-q-short" id="formEmail" type="email">
                </div>
                <div class="caja">
                    <div class="flecha"></div>
                    <label class="tituloform" for="email">Fecha de Evento
                    <span class="asterisk"></span>
                    </label>
                    <input name="fecha" class="ss-q-short" id="formFecha" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="caja">
                    <div class="flecha"></div>
                    <label class="tituloform" for="asunto">Asunto
                    </label>
                    <input name="asunto" class="ss-q-short" id="formAsunto" type="text">
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="punteadolargo" id="contacto"></div>
              <div class="raya" id="contacto"></div>
                <img src="img/mensaje.jpg" class="mensajecinta">
              <div class="mensaje">
              <div class="caja">
                    <label class="tituloform" for="mensaje">
                    </label>
                    <textarea name="mensaje" class="ss-q-short" id="formMensaje" form="web"></textarea>
                </div>
                </div>
            <div id="webFormResult"></div>
            <div>
                <p style="text-align:center">
                <input type="submit" value="" class="submit" name"submit"/>
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="global.js"></script>

        <!--form-->
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the mail.php that make it work:

```
<?php

$header = 'From: info@omgphotobooth.com.ar' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: '.$_POST["email"]. "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$msg = '';

foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    $msg .= "$k: $v \n";
}

$res = @mail('maiamaranghello@gmail.com', 'Contacto desde web', $msg, $header);

header('Content-type: text/json');


$res = true;

echo json_encode( array('result' => $res) );

?>
```

this is de js for the form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('form#web').submit(function(){

        var definitions = [
        {
            id: 'formNombre',
            type: 'string',
            title: 'nombre'
        },

        {
            id: 'formEmail',
            type: 'email',
            title: 'email'
        },

        {
            id: 'formAsunto',
            type: 'string',
            title: 'asunto'
        },
        {
            id: 'formMensaje',
            type: 'string',
            title: 'mensaje'
        }       
        ];

        if( formValidar($(this), definitions) ) {

            console.log($(this));

            $.post('mail.php', $(this).serialize(), function(json){

                if(json.result == true) {
                    $('#webFormResult').html('El mensaje se ha enviado correctamente!');
                } else {
                    $('#webFormResult').html('No pudimos enviar el mensaje, intente nuevamente');
                }
                $("#web input[type=text],#web input[type=email], #web input[type=number], #web textarea, #web select").val('');

            });

            return false;

        } else {
            return false;
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

One problem I see is that in the code that's visible you aren't including the jQuery library in your code. Try adding that to your code first and see how it works.

Also, you might want to remove the @ symbol as Amir noted in his post.

Comment: Oh, yes, you were right, that was the problem, I probably erase it by error. Thanks! Sometimes is good to have an extra view to find the problem!

Answer (score 1):

remove @ in mail.php

```
$res = @mail('maiamaranghello@gmail.com', 'Contacto desde web', $msg, $header);
```

/

```
$res = mail('maiamaranghello@gmail.com', 'Contacto desde web', $msg, $header);
```

also check you php.ini and make sure SMTP is working fine and required port (25) is open

Answer (score 1):

because you mention conent-type set the header is text/json maybe your browser is configured to download json instead of opening it.
You might need a plugin such as [JSONVIEW](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/jsonview/) to see it in your browser